# Uglify/minify Polymer web components using gulp

Tags: polymer, minify, uglifyjs

I am trying to minify my web components using gulp's uglify plugin but it fails because it does not recognize the custom html tags.

Are there any gulp plugins that can minify html containing custom tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this is quite the challenge. You use the [crisper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-crisper) plugin to factor out the script into it's own file. You can then minify the script source. Afterwards use [vulcanize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-vulcanize) to inline your script back into the HTML.

Answer (score 6):

Try out [gulp-htmlmin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-htmlmin).

I use it to minify my elements.html file after vulcanising, but I suppose it should work on non vulcanised elements just as well. 
Here's how I call the plugin inside my gulpfile:

```
.pipe(htmlmin({
    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
    customAttrAssign: [{"source":"\\$="}],
    customAttrSurround: [
        [ {"source": "\\({\\{"}, {"source": "\\}\\}"} ],
        [ {"source": "\\[\\["}, {"source": "\\]\\]"}  ]
    ],
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    // always leave one space
    // because http://perfectionkills.com/experimenting-with-html-minifier/#collapse_whitespace
    conservativeCollapse: true,
    minifyJS: true,
    minifyCSS: true,
    removeComments: true,
    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
    removeCDATASectionsFromCDATA: true
}))
```

Comment: This is a great answer! Thanks