# Polymer 1.0: Minify HTML,CSS while building

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer 2.0 provides option for minify html and css in polymer.json while building in Polymer CLI.
https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/build-for-production

but Polymer 1.0 does not provide that option and there is no documentation for that.

How this can be solved?

Comment: Maybe this will help you. Uglify/minify Polymer web components using gulp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213647/uglify-minify-polymer-web-components-using-gulp
Seems like you have to do quite some work.

Answer (score 0):

Polymer CLI works for Polymer 1, 2, and 3. That is, it can also minify Polymer 1 projects (e.g., [Polymer 1.x app template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042699/how-to-install-polymer-1-x-templates-with-polymer-cli)). Here's a minimal `polymer.json` configuration that minifies HTML, CSS, and JavaScript:

```
{
  "builds": [{
    "name": "my-build",
    "html": {
      "minify": true
    },
    "css": {
      "minify": true
    },
    "js": {
      "minify": true
    }
  }]
}
```